# Why does the scroll indicator not appear when I decelerate a scroll view manually?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I had good reasons to disable the default deceleration behavior of UIScrollView to implement my own.

What I do is this:

1) When the user finishes dragging, I start an NSTimer to decelerate.

2) The timer calls periodically a method which scrolls the scrollview like this:

```
[self setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.contentOffset.x, self.contentOffset.y + dy) animated:NO];
```

The scroll view decelerates nicely just the way how I want it.

But as soon as my timer kicks in to decelerate scrolling, the scroll indicator sticks with the contentView and slides up or down entirely, then disappears.

Calling `-flashScrollIndicators` doesn't help to make them visible while manually animating the scroll.

Did that also happen to anyone else?

Comment: I think that the `scrollIndicator`s are supposed to be used with the standard scroll behavior. You might have to *roll your own*...

Comment: It's hard to imagine any good reasons to do your own deceleration instead of using the default behavior. Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your timer on the main (GUI) thread?  If so, it might be locking the gui till the timer expires.  Try spinning off a new thread to run your timer and then implement a call back method using InvokeOnMainThread to update your scrollview to the desired location.